# Segmentation Fault during printing, includes large array computation

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

This program in C is supposed to delete every 666th number in a series of 10^7 natural numbers.

The problem seems to compile fine, even with optimisation. But, while on runtime stops throwing a Segmentation Fault after a few computations. I notice that when it stops its a few hundred thousand natural numbers away from the upper limit of 10^7. I at first tried to solve the problem using dynamic memory allocation with malloc. I received the same output. I tried using static arrays to do the job.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned int a[10000001] = {[0 ... 10000000] = 1};

void main(void) {

    unsigned int i = 1, last = 0, count = 0, test = 0;

    while(i < 100000) {
        count = 0; test = 0;

        while(count < 665) {
            if(a[last + count + test])
                count++;
            else
                test++;
        }

        last = last + test + count;

        if(last < 10000002)
            a[last] = 0;
        else {
            last = last - 10000001;
            a[last] = 0;
        }

        printf(" %u", last);

        i++;
    }

    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it in the normal way, e.g. run it under gdb or valgrind ?

Comment: One problem: `if(last < 10000002)` allows `a[10000001] = 0` which is an invalid reference. You should have `if (last < 10000001)`. Also, do you know for sure that `a[last + count + test]` us a valid reference (that `last + count + test` is less than `10000001`)?

Comment: What if `last` becomes `10000001`? Then you will write out of bounds of the array `a`.

Comment: I realised that. But the problem seems to originate at the print of 'last' deleted element. That's where the Segmentation Fault is thrown.

Comment: A `for` loop would be more natural than a `while` loop in this case.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you array is sized `10000001` and not `10000000`?

Comment: The devil is in the details..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one problem:

```
if(last < 10000002)
    a[last] = 0;
```

Should be:

```
if(last < 10000001)
    a[last] = 0;
```

Also, this statement might be an issue if `last + count + test` is > `10000000`:

```
if(a[last + count + test])
```

Comment: Aha! I used gdb and found that `if(a[last + count + test])` was causing the problem really.

Comment: @tvamsisai Should have used gdb before SO. :-D

Comment: @fiddlingbits apologies.